# Create Logic Apps workflow using SDK (C#) samples

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-logic-apps

We want to use Logic Apps for our solution. But we are new to Logic Apps. We want to know if it is possible to do the following using the Azure SDK.

- create logic apps workflow dynamically
- start / stop / delete workflow
- get status of running workflow

We want to do all of above from the C# code.

Thank you

Comment: Asking for samples or tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. There's already lots of documentation and tutorials on the Azure site itself.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I would second OP on this one, as Microsoft doesn't have any clear documentation on how to to do it Programmatically, there are a few other blogs there which describe the procedure, but most of them uses Preview versions of nuget packages, some of which are unlisted already. It's been 2 years, still no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at Azure official document about Azure Logic App to know [what are Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-what-are-logic-apps#logic-app-concepts). Azure Logic App support us to automate workflows and business processes. See [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/T694) about how to use Azure Logic Apps to automate business process. We can also use it to define [custom trigger and action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-examples-and-scenarios). We can also [monitor Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-monitor-your-logic-apps) to know its running status.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Logic Apps management SDK found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic/

Answer (score -1):

Here is the steps for Managing Azure Logic Apps using .NET SDK

https://www.servicebus360.com/blogs/managing-azure-logic-apps-using-net-sdk/

Comment: Please, do not rely on links only in your answers. Even if possibly helpful at the time, they may become defunct and useless. Please, try to make your answer as self-contained as reasonably possible instead.

Comment: This link no longer works rendering this answer useless